# Apache request_uri in the scope of VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

This code works perfectly in .htaccess or directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_uri} !^/dir/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/ [END]
```

but when put into VirtualHost it causes infinite redirection.

I've read documentation about diffrences between request_uri in scope of virtualhost and directory but I'm still unable to produce code that will work in virtualhost context. What should I change?

Comment: "I've read documentation about diffrences between request_uri in scope of virtualhost and directory" - what have you read? There is no difference in the value of the `REQUEST_URI` variable between virtualhost and directory context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have a conflict with mod_dir (and the `DirectoryIndex`). Although I'm surprised this "works perfectly in `.htaccess`" (unless you have something else that prevents a loop)?

If you rewrite to the bare directory, ie. `/dir/` then mod_dir will trigger an internal subrequest to `/dir/index.php` (or whatever your `DirectoryIndex` is set to) and this will likely trigger an endless loop (despite your `END` flag) since `/dir/index.php` matches `!^/dir/$`.

You should be rewriting directly to the index document and this should solve the problem. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^/?dir/$ /dir/index.php [END]
```

You don't need the `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `REQUEST_URI`, you can do the same check in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - which is marginally more efficient and saves you a directive.